# Suitable Food for moderate to High altitude trekking

Tags: food, high-altitude

I am preparing for an expedition which is going to be in Mid-July next year.

I am quite aware about the level of physical fitness that we require for such a trek, and I am preparing for it as well.

One thing that strikes my mind the most is regarding food/diet that I should follow during the expedition.

I am purely a veg guy. I do not eat Eggs as well. For that matter, few people have advised my to consume chocolates and Apples during the expedition. I am not exactly aware about the diet that I should follow. Can someone share if they have planned for similar kind of a thing?

Comment: At high altitudes, many people experience a loss of appetite. For this reason, I find it helpful to bring a variety of foods. It's hard to work up an appetite for eating the same thing over and over. Bringing only two things, like chocolate and apples, may not be a good idea for that reason. Apples are probably not very practical because of their low ratio of calories to weight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, as a thumb rule, when on high altitude treks, I do not go for any food which is digestion intensive. i.e, any food which required a lot of oxygen to get digested is not favorable.

You can always have chocolate bars/energy bars at higher altitudes. Herbal tea is something that keeps you hydrated and gives you decent amount of caffeine at the same time. The locals/sherpas would probably recommend garlic soups as well. I'm not entirely sure of the scientific significance of the same.

Since you are a pure vegetarian, and since you need good amount of carbs and proteins, the following should give you the required nutrition:

- Local made bread.
- Cheese.
- Fresh fruits(availability is highly improbable).
- Dried fruits/nuts.

Comment: Garlic has vasodilating (blood vessel widening) properties, which could help getting more oxygen pumped pumped around. It also has blood pressure lowering properties and it seems to increase red blood cell dead as well. Honestly I have no idea if I'd expect a net positive or negative effect from it. But if the locals recommend it...